# Regex to match cell formulas where is sheet name with uderscore aka Sheet1_2 in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: regex, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

Hi I need your help with Regex in LibreOffice 6.4 Calc.

**Situation:**

I have quite complex file with plenty sheets referring to each other using formulas in cells. Now I need to mass update formulas in about 10+ sheets, each referring to various sheets with a lot formulas...

The replacement of formulas can be done quite efficiently using `Find and Replace` and `Regular expressions`. I need to match `sheet name` and `row` and `column`. In fact I need to remove fixed anchors, ie `=Sheet1_2.$A$1` to become `=Sheet1_2.A1` on many variants of that example, ie different sheet names, columns and rows...

However I am facing to weird problem with matching the sheet name having underscore in its name, such as sheet named `Sheet1_2`.

**Example file:**

Here is very simplified example of the document I work in:

1. Create new Spreadsheet with two sheets named `Sheet1` and `Sheet1_2`.
2. On `Sheet1` type formula `=$Sheet1_2.$A$1` in its first cell.

**Action of replacement:**

In the `Find and Replace` dialogue I have this settings:

- Find: `(\$[A-Za-z0-9\_]*\.)\$([A-Z])\$`
- Replace: `$1$2`
- Search in: `Formulas`
- Other options: `[x] Regular expressions`.

**Result of Find All:**

- `=$Sheet2.$B$1` is matched (no underscore)
- `=$Sheet1_2.$A$1` is NOT matched (the underscore)

Official help does mention just the escaping: [LibreOffice 6.4 Help - List of Regular Expressions](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.4/en-GB/text/shared/01/02100001.html)

**The question:**

> Did I missed anything or what's the correct approach to match sheet name with underscore in cell formula?

Comment: this string has no leading underscore `=Sheet1_2.$A$1` you could make it optional `(\$?[A-Za-z0-9_]*\.)\$([A-Z])\$`

Comment: @Thefourthbird oops, it was a typo. The sheet name has always a preceding dollar sign in formulas. I have updated the question. Thanks for notifying me ;) The sheet name is still not matched anyway.

Comment: You don't have to escape the underscore in the characterclass btw, but can you check if this does work? Maybe there is another char `(\$[^.]+\.)\$([A-Z])\$`

Comment: @Thefourthbird No. `(\$[^.]+\.)\$([A-Z])\$` does not match =$Sheet1_2.$A$1

Comment: `(\$.*\.)\$([A-Z]*)\$` does NOT match it as well. `.*` does not match the underscore. Maybe its a bug in Calc.

Comment: So `.*` does find `=$Sheet2.$B$1` but it does not find `=$Sheet1_2.$A$1`?

Comment: Just for your information, your own attempt, and those sugested by @Thefourthbird,  actually worked for me using `LibreOfficeDev Calc 6.4`. Not sure if this is a bug, but I remember updating to this particular build since `FILTERXML()` also had a particular annoying bug that needed fixing.

Comment: Damn. I got a typo in my testing sheet!  I missed `$A$1`. So the correct Regex is `(\$[A-Za-z0-9_]*\.)\$?([A-Z])\$?` 
Thank you guys for troubleshooting with me @JvdV and @Thefourthbird . Going to mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Correct finally I found the problem was not underscore `_` but typo in my testing file that has some variants with and without anchors such as `=$Sheet2_1.A1`, `=$Sheet2_1.$A$1`

The correct regex is with optional dollars: `(\$[A-Za-z0-9\_]*\.)\$?([A-Z])\$?`. Note: The underscore does not need to be escaped, of course.

Thanks @Thefourthbird and @JvdV for troubleshooting ;)